# Custom Protocol Not Sending Messages

Tags: ios, protocols

I've looked at some tutorials and even watched Apple's WWDC 2011 video on how to create custom protocol to send data backwards and it seems I'm missing something but I can't pinpoint exactly what.  I have an addUrination view controller which is pushed onto the stack from view controller Charts.  I created a protocol and a delegate property in addUrination.h in attempt to be able to send a message to Charts when a data entry is submitted.  When the data entry is submitted, I call the message I created in my custom protocol and have implemented in Charts.m but the message is never sent since my NSLog call never appears in the console.  I remembered to set the delegate when preparing for the segue from Charts.m as well.  Thanks for any information because understanding what's wrong with this will help immensely in learning how to send messages backwards.

**AddUrination.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class AddUrination;
@protocol AddUrinationDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)addUrinationViewController:(AddUrination *)controller didFinishEnteringUrination:(NSNumber *)urination;

@end

@interface AddUrination : UITableViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (weak,nonatomic) id<AddUrinationDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

**AddUrination.m**

```
-(IBAction)addUrination:(id)sender
{
PFObject *amount=[PFObject objectWithClassName:@"urinationAmount"];
NSNumberFormatter *number=[[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init];
[number setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSNumber *urinateAmount=[number numberFromString:self.addUrinationTextField.text];

/*Create activity indicator*/
UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner=[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
[spinner setCenter:CGPointMake(self.tableView.frame.size.width/2.0,(self.tableView.frame.size.height-self.keyboardHeight)/2.0)];
spinner.layer.backgroundColor=[[UIColor blackColor]CGColor];
spinner.layer.cornerRadius=10;
[self.view addSubview:spinner];

[spinner startAnimating];
if(urinateAmount!=nil){
    [amount setObject:urinateAmount forKey:@"amountOfUrine"];
    PFUser *user=[PFUser currentUser];
    [amount setObject:user forKey:@"user"];
    [amount saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if(!error) {
            [spinner stopAnimating];
            UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Thank You!" message:@"Your urination amount has been successfully saved" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
            UrinationData *dataSettings=[UrinationData sharedUrinationData];
            [dataSettings setUrinationDataChanged:YES];
            self.addUrinationTextField.text=@"";
            [self.delegate addUrinationViewController:self didFinishEnteringUrination:urinateAmount];
            [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        }
        else{
            [spinner stopAnimating];
            UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Uh-oh!" message:@"There was an error on our end. Please try again!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
        }
    }];
}
else{
    [spinner stopAnimating];
    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Uh-oh!" message:@"Please enter a valid amount" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Sorry" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
}
}
```

**Charts.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h"
#import "CPTAnimation.h"
#import "AddUrination.h"


@interface Charts :     UIViewController<CPTPlotDataSource,CPTPlotSpaceDelegate,CPTScatterPlotDelegate,CPTScatterPlotDataSource,CPTAnimationDelegate,UIGestureRecognizerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIAlertViewDelegate,AddUrinationDelegate>

@property(nonatomic,strong)CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace;
@property(nonatomic,strong)CPTXYGraph *graph;
@property(nonatomic,strong)CPTGraphHostingView *hostingView;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *graphTitle;
@property(nonatomic,strong)UISegmentedControl *chartsSegmentedControl;
@property(nonatomic,strong)CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation *urinationAnnotation;

@end
```

**Charts.m**

```
-(void)addUrinationViewController:(AddUrination *)controller didFinishEnteringUrination:(NSNumber *)urination{
NSLog(@"Urination was entered from add urination screen");
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
// Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
// Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"AddUrinationSegue"]){
    AddUrination *addUrination=[segue destinationViewController];
    addUrination.delegate=self;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems everything fine, you just need to check whether, method calling line is executing or not and check control goes in these lines or not and Reference of self. Please, let me know

```
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"AddUrinationSegue"]){
    AddUrination *addUrination=[segue destinationViewController];
    addUrination.delegate=self;
}
```

Comment: Yes that was it.  Charts.m are the pages of a page controller so the segue actually being called from my view controller container which holds the page view controller. Now I'm unable to add an item to the navigation bar to perform a segue from charts.m

Comment: I tried adding the button to the navigation bar by calling self.parentViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButton but that didn't work.  It's more useful to send the message to the pages rather than the container in my mind

Comment: it's okay i hope my fix is proper. My protocol sends a message to the container view controller whose responsibility is then to alert the page that it needs to update its content by calling a function from the current page in view